# prove if $ T^k=0$ for some $k$, only $1$ eigenvalue $=0$ proof help!

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map for which $T^k = 0$  for some $k > 0$.
 Assume $V \neq \left\{ 0 \right\}$. Prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, and that it is the only eigenvalue of $T$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $v \neq 0$ be an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $Tv=\lambda v$ and $$T^kv =\lambda ^k v$$

That is $$0=\lambda^k v$$

Hence $\lambda$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial must divide $p(x)=x^k$. This means that the minimal polynomial contains only powers of $x$ and hence has only $x=0$ as a root with some multiplicity less than or equal to $k$.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill? :-)

Comment: You don't need Cayley-Hamilton. If $T^k=0$ then $X^k$ annihilates $T$, so its minimal polynomial divides $X^k$.

Comment: @arkeet perhaps, but the simple solution was taken